# problem in select into query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why m i getting error `incorrect syntax near the keyword  IN` in the following query?

```
select * into persons_backup IN 'HRMS.mdb' from persons
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Assuming SQL Server (based on your previous question) you would need

```
select * 
into persons_backup 
from HRMS.mdb.persons
```

or

```
select * 
into HRMS.mdb.persons_backup 
from persons
```

dependant upon what you are trying to do exactly. [See `SELECT ... INTO` syntax here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

Comment: I tried ur second option but it says "The specified schema name "mdb" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it." Please clarify how can i get rid of that. Secondly, whats wrong with my query(specified in the ques)? The syntac i hav used is the one specied in w3schools.

Comment: I had to guess what you are trying to do as your question just provides invalid syntax with no explanatory text. `HRMS.mdb.persons` is ih the format `databasename.schemaname.tablename` If you don't have a schema called `mdb` then what are you trying to do exactly? To `SELECT ... INTO` a table in your default schema just use `select * into persons_backup from persons`

Comment: i want to create backup of persons table in another database called "HRMS". This database already exists.

Comment: This is another SQL Server Datbase? If so why does your query have `.mdb` If there is no such schema? You need to create this schema or use a different existing one. e.g. `select * into HRMS.dbo.persons_backup from persons`

Comment: @vatspoo - Ah right [looks like the syntax you were trying to use is for Microsoft Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/select-into-statement-HP001032266.aspx) not SQL Server

Comment: Ok now i understood whats dbo. I got the backup but the table persons_backup consists null value n not the values of the persons table.

Comment: In fact when i am using the command "select * from persons" it shows single record with almost all the values null. while when i open the table by right clicking it, full table is visible. Can u plz tell me why is it so?

Comment: Dunno. That behaviour doesn't make any sense to me unless you have 2 different `persons` tables in different databases or different schemas and are looking at 2 different tables.

Comment: But there exists only one persons table.

Comment: Well as I said that doesn't make any sense to me. You should start a new question about this explaining exactly what you are doing to get this result and where you are doing it as it has nothing to do with the `SELECT ... INTO` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add all rows from persons into another table persons_backup:

```
Insert into persons_backup select * from persons;
```

Depending on the RDBMS you use, you might have to put () around the select.

Comment: For using this query i will hav to create the "persons_backup" table first. I am trying to use select into for creating backup.